# Animation loop with RxJs

Tags: rxjs

**What I want to achieve:**

I want to create an animation loop with RxJs. The logic is following:

1. Every `x` ms load new frame (load image from web)
2. If the previous frame is still loading, skip the loading of the next frame.
3. If the animation completes (all images were loaded and displayed), stop for `x` ms and then start the animation loop again.

**What I've got so far:**

Stream for interval:

`private intervalStream: Observable<number> = interval(800);`

Observable which emits `true` if frame is loading and `false` if not:

`this.frameStateService.isAnyFrameLoading`

the method, which starts the animation:

```
public startAnimation(): void {    

    const combined = combineLatest(this.intervalStream, this.layerStateService.isAnyLayerLoading);

    combined.pipe(
        map(
            ([interval, isLayerLoading]) => {
                if(!isLayerLoading && !this.frameStateService.isAnyFrameLoading) {
                    this.frameStateService.setCurrentFrameToNextFrame();
                } else {
                    timeout(5000);
                }
            }
        )
    ).subscribe();
}
```

**Diagram:**

```
interval   ----x----x----x----x----x----x----x
isLoading  f---t--f-t------f--t---ft---------- (f - false, t - true)
```

**What is not working:**

1. It doesn't wait till a layer is loaded.
2. The animation doesn't restart after final delay.

Comment: Do you have a different list of images (frames) that you want to load every `x` seconds or do you have a single file containing different images (frames)?

Comment: I have list of images.

Answer (score 0):

I think this would be better implemented around `exhaustMap` because it'll ignore all emissions from source until inner Observable completes.

```
import { interval, of } from 'rxjs';
import { exhaustMap, take, repeat, concat, delay, ignoreElements } from 'rxjs/operators';

const loadImage = () => of('img')

interval(1000)
  .pipe(
    exhaustMap(() => loadImage()), // wait until loadImage completes
    take(10), // number of frames
    concat(of(null).pipe( // delay after animation completes
      delay(5000),
      ignoreElements(),
    )),
    repeat(), // repeat the whole process
  )
  .subscribe(console.log);
```

Live demo: https://stackblitz.com/edit/rxjs6-demo-j9wl38?file=index.ts

Comment: Why `concat(of(null).pipe( // delay after animation completes
      delay(5000),
      ignoreElements(),
    ))` and not simply `delay(5000)`?

Comment: `delay()` itself can't be used as a source Observable.

Comment: Actually if I use your code I get an error "Argument of type 'Observable<never>' is not assignable to parameter of type 'OperatorFunction<string, {}>'.
  Type 'Observable<never>' provides no match for the signature '(source: Observable<string>): Observable<{}>'." while if I use just `delay(500)` it seems I get the desired result - Rxjs 6.3.2 with TypeScript 3.0.3

Comment: I have seen - still I see also the error in my VSCode

Answer (score 0):

I would propose to look at this approach, some sort of variation to what @martin wrote before.

You have 2 ingredients:

- a list of file names (`files`) you get from somewhere (e.g. a service you
  call)
- a function (`readFile`) that reads each file - let's assume that such function
  returns an Observable which emits when the file content is read and
  notifies the file content itself

You can create an Observable that emits the name of the file to be read, each emission distanced by a certain delay (800ms in your case), and then wait `x` ms before repeating. Something like this

```
const files = [
  'F1',
  'Second file',
  '3rd file',
  'file n 4'
];

const imagesToShow = from(files).pipe(
  mergeMap(f => of(f).pipe(delay(800)), 1)
);

const imagesToShowRepeated = imagesToShow.pipe(
  delay(5000),
  repeat()
)
```

Now you can leverage `exhaustMap` to get what you want, if my understanding is right, like in the following lines

```
const loadFile = (fileName: string) => {
  return of(fileName).pipe(delay(Math.random()*2000)); // simulates the function reading a file
}

const animation = imagesToShowRepeated.pipe(
  exhaustMap(file => loadFile(file))
)
```